# [ios]add observer to Target Application from the Framework or custom static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, observer-pattern

I have developed an ios `lib/framework` where i record user login and connect to the server and fetch data from server real time.
In the same `library/framework` I would like to add observer to my application so that I come to know when the app went in background or became active again.

Something similar to what we usually do in the application code itself....(my test application code below. An observer functionality that i want to move to the common `lib/framework`)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MyAppWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

But even though i have defined the method as

```
void MyAppWillResignActive(id self, SEL _cmd, id application) {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question is incomplete

Comment: Aren't you able to call that function? Explain this completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the signature of the method to be invoked in your selector `MyAppWillResignActive`.

EDIT: *Moved registration to library initialization as suggested in iosDeveloper09 comment.*

---

#### Class level

- Register during `initialize`

  ```
  + (void)initialize {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
       name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
       object:nil];
  }
  ```
- Class handler `+`

  ```
  + (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
  ```

#### Instance level

- Register during `init`

  ```
  - (instancetype)init
  {
      self = [super init];
      if (self) {
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
           addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
           name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
           object:nil];
      }
      return self;
  }
  ```
- Instance handler `-`

  ```
  - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
  ```

#### Host

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SO_41526719Library * lib;

// Keep an instance around
self.lib = [[SO_41526719Library alloc] init];
```

---

**At runtime**

> applicationWillResignActive NSConcreteNotification 0x6000000545e0 {name = UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification; object = }

Comment: Thanks SwiftArchitect it works fine for me . Further I called registerForNotifications( ) method in the lib init function itself so that the observer binding happens automatically.